# Is there a way to dynamically create new arrays from a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, dynamic-programming

I have a table that looks like

```
|Category|number|absorbance|protein1|protein2|
|--------|------|----------|--------|--------|
|a|int|float|float|float|
|a|int|float|float|float|
|a|int|float|float|float|
|a|int|float|float|float|
|b|int|float|float|float|
|b|int|float|float|float|
|b|int|float|float|float|
|b|int|float|float|float|
|b|int|float|float|float|
|c|int|float|float|float|
|c|int|float|float|float|
|c|int|float|float|float|
|c|int|float|float|float|
|c|int|float|float|float|
```

and I want to extract vectors of absorbance, protein1, and protein2 for a,b,
and c.

There could be more than 3 categories and each category need not have the same number in another category. Is there something built into dataframes that can extract these subarrays?

I tried dynamically coding this using

```
julia
for sample_num=1:number_samples
    for i=1:3
        #determine col type
        if i==1
            data_col_name="abs"
        elseif i==2
            data_col_name="B-actin"
        else
            data_col_name="pink-1"
        end
        temp=string(sample_num,"_",data_col_name)
        column_count=4*(sample_num-1)+i
        @eval($:string(sample_num,data_col_name)=$file_contents[:,column_count])
        #string_as_varname(temp,file_contents[:,column_count])
    end
end
```

But I got error in method definition:

```
function Base.string must be explicitly imported to be extended
top-level scope@none:0
top-level scope@none:1
eval@boot.jl:360[inlined]
top-level scope@Local: 13[inlined]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully clear what you need exactly, but most likely what you are looking for is `GroupedDataFrame`.

You start with creating it:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(id=["a", "a", "b", "b"], col1=1:4, col2=11:14)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ id      col1   col2
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ a           1     11
   2 │ a           2     12
   3 │ b           3     13
   4 │ b           4     14

julia> gdf = groupby(df, :id)
GroupedDataFrame with 2 groups based on key: id
First Group (2 rows): id = "a"
 Row │ id      col1   col2
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ a           1     11
   2 │ a           2     12
⋮
Last Group (2 rows): id = "b"
 Row │ id      col1   col2
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ b           3     13
   2 │ b           4     14
```

Now to get column `:col1` from group `"a"` you can just write:

```
julia> gdf[("a",)].col1
2-element view(::Vector{Int64}, [1, 2]) with eltype Int64:
 1
 2
```

You can also define the group value and column name programmatically e.g.:

```
julia> group = "b"
"b"

julia> column = "col2"
"col2"

julia> gdf[(group,)][:, column]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 13
 14
```

EDIT

How to get a dictionary mapping (key, column) pairs into subvectors:

```
julia> Dict((key[1], col) => gdf[key][:, col] for key in keys(gdf), col in valuecols(gdf))
Dict{Tuple{String, Symbol}, Vector{Int64}} with 4 entries:
  ("a", :col2) => [11, 12]
  ("b", :col2) => [13, 14]
  ("a", :col1) => [1, 2]
  ("b", :col1) => [3, 4]
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. But is there a way to automate exporting each column of each group into a new  vector array with the name of the vector reflect the group and column? I don't want to hard-code in separate vectors for each column of each group, because this will be used to process csv files of different number of groups

Comment: Again - it is not fully clear what you want. In particular it is not clear what you mean by "vector array". Maybe you can give an example of the desired output data structure? For example you can store the result as a dictionary. I have given you the code how to do it in edit.